# Use storyboard or xib for single view controller?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have to implement the layout of a single screen, which is not connected to the overall app flow, and I was wondering if it makes sense to use a Storyboard.

Storyboards make sense for flow/navigation (multiple controller), have some convenient features like, iirc prototype cells which are not available in xib. And it also makes sense if I think maybe later the screen may become a "story" (more view controllers). But none of this advantages are useful for my particular case.

I was thinking anyways in using Storyboard, as it seems to be a bit more flexible than xib generally, but is there any disadvantage? Maybe performance penalty or such? Is there a preferred way to setup single view controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go ahead..take the advantages of using storyboard. There is no disadvantages or performance issues particular to storyboards when compared to xib files. Its all about your convenience. As you said the single view controller may become a story in future, then the storyboard would be a right decision. And when to use xib? thats upto you, one ideal situation where i will choose xib is, if i have an independent controller that i want to share with other project also then i would choose xib.

Comment: But couldn't you share also the storyboard? Or what case do you mean specifically?

Comment: Ya you can share storyboard also, you can have multiple storyboard in a project. But sharing a storyboard for a single controller is not convenient since storyboard always represents a group of controllers and xib file can easily identify a single controller. In your case even if it is a single controller its part of your main app flow(considering future it may expand) so that i recommended you to use storyboard. No harm in that

Comment: I agree that storyboard is the best fit for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The performance penalty would only bother under the circumstance which too many controllers (more than 10) with segues were squeezed in one Storyboard. Everything would be totally fine before that.

Answer (score -1):

And if you have more than two people are trying to edit same storyboard file than you have to resolve conflict, which will be more tedious job.

Storyboard benefits:
a. easy demo purpose and fast implementation.
b. small team like two person.
c. Storyboard is providing complete view and navigation model.

XIB benefits:
a. You can modularize your code.
b. More people can work on different-different controller without affecting your xib or code.

Comment: You know that you can split storyboards, right? I'm talking about a storyboard which would *only* contain my single view controller, the rest is in other storyboards.